# Is there a max stack depth in EOSIO?

Tags: smart-contract

For ethereum it is 1024, is there one for EOSIO, if so what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for `call depth`:
250 by default (and all public eosio networks I'm aware of).

for `action depth`:
it is controlled by `default_max_inline_action_depth` chain configuration parameter. It defaults to 4, but on mainnet it's 10 at the moment. you also have to be aware of the `inline actions` which exist on EOSIO blockchains. inline actions aren't equivalent to "message calls" (is this the right term on ETH?). message calls are synchronous whereas inline actions on EOSIO occur after (but not necessarily directly after) the currently running action.

Comment: hm is that the action depth?  or if you can elaborate on what call depth is.  In ETH you can only do max 1024 actions before you get a max stack error.

Comment: @Nat I added a bit more info which I managed to find for this topic